# Accessing Multiple value in python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

My program should register the location of an element in a channel. Each of the elements will have a different `GroupClass` (e.g., `Class1`, `Class2`, `Class3`).

For example, the following code should give the location of `A1`, `B1` and `C1` as 6, 3 and 4, respectively:

```
GroupClass = {'Class1': 'A1', 'Class2': 'B1', 'Class3': 'C1'}
channels = ['E1', 'g', 'A2', 'B1', 'C1', 'A3', 'A1']

labels = []
picks = []
for ch in GroupClass:
    if not GroupClass[ch]: continue
    ch_pick = GroupClass[ch]  # Investigate this                                                                              filename, channels))
    picks.append(channels.index(ch_pick.upper()))
    labels.append(ch)

print(picks)
print(labels)
```

However, the code fail when more than one element was assigned in the dict.
For example, the following will give an error:

```
GroupClass = {'Class1': ('A1', 'A2'), 'Class2': 'B1', 'Class3': 'C1'}
```

By changing the GroupClass as above, the var picks and labels should produce

**picks**= 6,2,3,4
**labels**= {'Class1': 'A1', 'Class2': 'B1', 'Class3': 'C1'}

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So what should happen in that case; what should be done when the value in `GroupClass` consists of a tuple with multiple strings?

Comment: probably you get AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper', so get each item from tuple and do upper case

Comment: Your sample output, which you added later, is strange.  There is no `pickes` or `label`, it is `picks` and `labels`.  You seem to require `labels` to be a dictionary, but you create a list, and I'm not sure what type you expect `picks` to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check the class of the object and use multiple entries in a list:

```
GroupClass = {'Class1': ('A1','A2'), 'Class2': 'B1', 'Class3': 'C1'}
channels= ['E1', 'g', 'A2', 'B1', 'C1', 'A3', 'A1']

labels=[]
picks = []
for ch in GroupClass:
    if not GroupClass[ch]: continue
    ch_pick = GroupClass[ch]  # Investigate this

    if isinstance(ch_pick, tuple):
        for i in ch_pick:
            picks.append(channels.index(i.upper()))
    else:
        picks.append(channels.index(ch_pick.upper()))

    labels.append(ch)

print(picks)
print(labels)
```

Gives:

```
[6, 2, 3, 4]
['Class1', 'Class2', 'Class3']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it answer the question

Answer (score 2):

That is because when you do `(channels.index(ch_pick.upper()))` it is expected that `ch_pick` is a string. In this case it is an `tuple`.

And as the error message suggests **`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper'`**.

What you can do is pick a element(first/ second etc) if data type is `tuple` by doing something like this:

```
if type(ch_pick) is tuple:
   // pick an element then append    
else:          
   picks.append(channels.index(ch_pick.upper()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is pretty clear :

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'map'

My answer :

```
for ch in GroupClass:
    if not GroupClass[ch]: continue
    ch_pick = GroupClass[ch]  # Investigate this filename, channels))
    if isinstance(ch_pick, tuple):picks.append([channels.index(x.upper())  for x in ch_pick])
    else : picks.append(channels.index(ch_pick.upper()))
    labels.append(ch)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the solution, appreciate it